Ask query returns results true but select query return nothing
I do not know what I am doing wrong. I have the following Ask sparql query which returns true (what I expect). The same query but using select returns nothing. There are no errors.
Here are my queries:
String askQuery1 = "Ask WHERE {?x   <http://www.example.org#share>   <http://example.com/MediaCoverage/l.premierleague.com-2020-coverage>. "
            + "<< ?x  <http://www.example.org#share> <http://example.com/MediaCoverage/l.premierleague.com-2020-coverage> >>  <http://purl.org/specialprivacy/splog#occurs> ?t . \r\n"
            + " FILTER (?t <\"2021-02-25T21:00:00Z\"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime> ) } \r\n";
String selectQuery2 = "SELECT * WHERE {?x   <http://www.example.org#share>   <http://example.com/MediaCoverage/l.premierleague.com-2020-coverage>. "
            + "<< ?x  <http://www.example.org#share> <http://example.com/MediaCoverage/l.premierleague.com-2020-coverage> >>  <http://purl.org/specialprivacy/splog#occurs> ?t . \r\n"
            + " FILTER (?t <\"2021-02-25T21:00:00Z\"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime> ) } \r\n";

This is the code that I use to retrieve results:
String logFile1 ="C:/Extension/kb-traces.ttl";

    Dataset dataset1;
    dataset1 = RDFDataMgr.loadDataset(logFile1) ;
    
    
    // test ask query
    Boolean exist = false;
    String askSparql = askQuery1;
    Query sparql = QueryFactory.create(askSparql);
    QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(sparql, dataset1);
    boolean result = qe.execAsk();
    if(result == true){
        exist= true;
    }
    System.out.println(exist);
    
    // test select query
    Query sparql1 = QueryFactory.create(selectQuery2);
    QueryExecution qe1 = QueryExecutionFactory.create(sparql1, dataset1);
    ResultSet results = qe1.execSelect();
    
    System.out.println(results.getRowNumber());

     if (results.hasNext()) {
        while (results.hasNext()) {
            QuerySolution qs = results.next();
            ResultSetFormatter.out(results);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("No results found");
    

    }

Can you tell me if I'm doing something wrong?
I can also share my log file if you're interested.

returns nothing means it prints "No results found"? I'm asking because inside the loop results.next does already consume one solution binding. In cases there is only one matching your data, ResultSetFormatter.out(results); would print an empty set

you should only do if (results.hasNext()) {             ResultSetFormatter.out(results);     } to print the whole resultset

also, why not doing boolean exists = qe.execAsk(); instead of the declaration in advance + the if clause to bind the value?

@UninformedUser removing while (results.hasNext()) { ..} solved the issue. Thank ypu for your prompt reply. Also I have to say, it was illogical that the message "No results found" wasn't displayed to me assuming no results are found, which fits with your response.

@UninformedUser, I didn't get your last reply regarding the qe.execAsk. I am already using the "if" clause  to check for "exists" ...
